# Trying to access order items details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a function to display different custom thank you pages according to which product you purchased. The shop is simple, you can make a one-time donation or register for monthly donations to a non-profit. I want to display different thank you pages depending on whether which you did. I have several monthly donation products and one for one-time, separated into differnt categories. What I want to do is get the category of the products just purchased (one can only order either, not both, at a time), and use that to display the correct message.

```
function get_order_cat($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    print_r($items); // Returns the data, but it's protected !
}
```

This returns an array of objects, but the data is :protected. Any tips on how to access this, or get the result I'm looking for another way?

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve categories with that :

```
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);


    foreach ($order->get_items("line_item") as $id_line_item => $item) {

        $product_ID = $item->get_product_id();

        $categories = get_the_terms($product_ID, "product_cat");



    }
```